# Xquery returns multiple values instead of one

Tags: xquery

Consider the xml file:

```
<warehouse>
- may be some tag on upper level of dep present, may be not
<dep no ="2">
    <item>
        <itemName> Item 1  </itemName>
        <supplier> Supp1 </supplier>
        <supplier> Supp2 </supplier>
    </item>
</dep>
<dep no ="1">
    <item>
        <itemName> Item 2  </itemName>
        <supplier> Supp1 </supplier>
        <supplier> Supp3 </supplier>
    </item>
</dep>
.......
</warehouse>
```

Note: There might be some tags above dep tag or they may be missing.

I need to show the list of suppliers in a list, item names they produce and infront of each item the department name, e.g.

```
Supp2
 Item1, 2
Supp1
 Item1, 2
 Item2, 1
```

This is my Code:

```
<ul>
{
for $sup in distinct-values(doc("warehouse.xml")//supplier)
for $item in doc("warehouse.xml")//item[supplier = $sup]

return <li>{data($sup)} <ul> {
let $n:= $item/itemName
let $y:= doc("warehouse.xml")//dep[//itemName=$n]/@no 
for $n1 in $n return <li>{data($n1), data($y)} </li>} </ul> </li>
}
</ul>
```

I am facing two problems. First is that y shows all department numbers, starting from 1. Another is that if I have 1 supplier that produces two items, instead of

```
Supp1
 Item1, 2
 Item2, 3
```

I get

```
Supp1
 Item1, 1,2, ...
Supp1
 Item2, 1,2, ...
```

Could you please suggest what could be wrong? I am deeply grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being new to XQuery I could write up the following.

Input:

```
<warehouse>
  <something/>
  <dep no ="2">
    <item>
      <itemName>Item1</itemName>
      <supplier>Supp1</supplier>
      <supplier>Supp2</supplier>
    </item>
  </dep>
  <anything/>
  <dep no ="1">
    <item>
      <itemName>Item2</itemName>
      <supplier>Supp1</supplier>
      <supplier>Supp3</supplier>
    </item>
  </dep>
  <whatever/>
</warehouse>
```

Query:

```
<ul>{
(: the ../text() can be dropped from everywhere :)
let $doc := doc("input.xml")    
for $supplier in distinct-values($doc//supplier/text())
let $items := $doc//item[supplier/text() = $supplier]/itemName/text()
return <li>{$supplier}: {string-join($items, ", ")}</li>
}</ul>
```

Output:

```
<ul>
  <li>Supp1: Item1, Item2</li>
  <li>Supp2: Item1</li>
  <li>Supp3: Item2</li>
</ul>
```

The *theory* behind the query is the following.

- Because you want to list item names for every supplier you basically want to *group by suppliers*. For this you have to iterate over every unique supplier present in the input:

  ```
  distinct-values($doc//supplier/text())
  ```
- After this you want to list every item associated with a given supplier:

  ```
  $doc//item[supplier/text() = $supplier]/itemName/text()
  ```

  which means you grab every item in the input whose supplier name is equal to the given supplier's name, and than you get the name of these (filtered) items.

And that was it. Hope I made some sense!

Comment: Deeply grateful for your reply. I am using Oxygen, and it seems "group by" is not defined there. (http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp) Any suggestions?

Comment: @PiotrL. Oh yeah, that's a nice little extra defined in XQuery 3.0. It seems your XQuery processor doesn't supports it just yet. I've updated my answer so that it doesn't use this feature.